# Understanding What A Walk Is In Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

My book gives the following definition:

[image]

My understanding of what a $x-y$ walk is right now is a loop free sequence of edges and vertices which begins at vertex $x$ and ends at vertex $y$. I'm confused as to why this definition says $x = y$ in the third line, can anyone explain this? They say that $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily distinct but then say they are equal. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notion of a walk is correct.  In this case,   *x* represents the "starting point" of the walk and *y* represents the "ending point."  Therefore, the first member of the sequence, x sub 0, will equal the starting vertex, *x*.  The final member of the sequence, x sub n, will equal the ending vertex, *y*.

I feel that you're taking the book's notation to mean

*x* = sequence = *y*

which is not true. *x* equals the first member of the sequence and *y* equals the final member of the sequence.

Perhaps it would be more clear if the book notated the line with parentheses.

(*x* = x sub 0), e sub 1, x sub 1...

...e sub n, (x sub n = *y*)

Comment: I see now, thanks so much. Could I just rewrite it as $x,e_1,x_1,e_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},e_n,y$? That way makes a little more sense to me, and I feel it is equally correct.

Comment: Yes, you could.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks man